# autohotkey unix miliseconds

Tags: time, autohotkey

```
#persistent
SetTimer, CheckTime, 0 ;check ms all the time
Return

CheckTime:
if (A_Now == 2022 01 19 10 00 00 and A_MSec == 000)
 SendInput {Enter}
 Sleep, 100
Return
```

Hi, I can't figure out what it's wrong. Is this even possible?
I want to reduce sending that button to below 00.100Z in Unix milliseconds

Comment: There's so much wrong with this, that I don't think it's really worth trying to point it all out. Could you maybe try to better describe what you're trying to do, so can post an actual solution for that?

Comment: Hi, I was trying to do hotkey that could press enter once at specified time as fast as possible for example: 10:00:00:000Z

Comment: Can someone help me?:

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.